# Permissions for creating a trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

mysql ver is 5.0.67

my trigger code is :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER upd_price BEFORE UPDATE ON product_price
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO update_price_log (product_id, product_price_old, product_price_new) values(OLD.product_id, OLD.product_price, NEW.product_price);
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

error is:

> #1227 - Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation

my server, is not cpanel!
it is : DirectAdmin Web Control Panel.

how can i create SUPER privilege and create my trigger?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must have MySQL Root privileges to set the SUPER permission for a user.

```
GRANT SUPER 
ON '<database>'.'<tablename/*>' 
TO '<username>'@'<host/connection/ip/%>';
```

Comment: Ah that was my problem. I granted permission to the local host user but not to the connection from my workstation.

Comment: not valid anymore, you can set triggers  for your own account without suuper  rights

Comment: @Blauhirn how? I am using shared hosting and I am not able to create triggers

Comment: you need mysql 5.1, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19823122/3779853 . so your answer is only valid for <= 5.0. I can confirm that, since I was using triggers on a IaaS hosting service recently

Answer (score 6):

I tried to give SUPER privilede on database.table level, but it fails, so I did

```
grant super on *.* to 'my_user'@'localhost';
```

then created my triggers. But don't forget to revoke it

```
revoke super on *.* from 'my_user'@'localhost';
```

Because it's a dangerous privilege to leave it granted in internet database

Answer (score 3):

Another way to create trigger without SUPER privilege by adding the following line to my.cnf or my.ini `log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1`

Comment: to set this also you need super privileges

Comment: With MySQL 8.0, now I get `SQL Error [1227] [42000]: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SET_USER_ID privilege(s) for this operation`

Answer (score 1):

Another way around [this bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39489), if acceptable, is to disable [binary logging](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log.html).

I have done this because I am not using a replication server, nor am I doing backups from the binlogs for recovery. But it might not be appropriate in your situation.

To do it, just comment out `log_bin` and `log_bin_index` lines in your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Now trigger privilege works fine without SUPER.