# Triggers not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a trigger in My sql , but when i write the below code the page keeps on loading and no output is shown.
My code is :-

```
DELIMITER$$ 
CREATE TRIGGER `tutorial`.`before_delete_books`  
    BEFORE DELETE ON `books` FOR EACH ROW  
    BEGIN  
        SELECT * FROM role;
    END $$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Is Rollback activated in ur Mysql? if it is u need to right a query to deny rollback

Comment: Since you've specified that you're working in PHP, what does your PHP code look like?

Comment: ya rollback is activated

Comment: @SDC i tried the above code in phpMyAdmin

Comment: @OMTheEternity Now there is no roll back, still not working

Comment: Are you even running appropriate MySQL version which supports triggers at all?

Comment: @PavanK you need to have SUPER priviledges to create a trigger: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404107/permissions-for-creating-a-trigger-in-mysql. Do you have them? Try creating a trigger from phpMyAdmin from the same user you connect in php. At least, we could see the error.

Comment: I have priviledges, ok wil try as u said

Comment: ERROR:-                                                          MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELIMITER$$ 
CREATE TRIGGER `tutorial`.`before_delete_books`  
    BEFORE DELET' at line 1

Comment: @PavanK Check the syntax carefully.

Comment: @user4035 iguess the syntax is proper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes finally i found solution for my own question........
There are actually few criteria to look before executing the triggers.
1. The data table you are executing must be of engine Innodb.
if its not innodb change it by writing this query.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Check the syntax , the proper syntax is

```
create trigger trigname after insert on lib_db.books
for each row
insert into role(role_id,role) values(5,'sometext');
end;
```

Make sure the delimeter is changed to some symbol lik $$. Because the default delimeter is ;