# How to populate a table when another table is populated?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want the table **cart** to be populated when I populate the table **cart_utilizador** and the table **cart** will be populated with `CURDATE();` on the field *datas*. How can I achieve this using triggers?

DATABASE diagram:
[image: Database diagram]

I tried this but the *`ON`* gives me an error saying "Unexpected ON":

```
CREATE TRIGGER cart_trigger
   ON cart_utilizador AFTER UPDATE
   AS
     INSERT INTO cart (id, datas)
       SELECT id_cart, CURDATE()
       FROM cart_utilizador;
```

Comment: which sql database?

Comment: Mysql @maSTAShuFu

Comment: Use trigger to achieve the same.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai do you have any specific site from wich I can guide myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a trigger. The trigger should fire up when you insert data into cart_utilizador, you can try this :

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_cart BEFORE INSERT
ON cart FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO cart_utilizador(datas) values(now());
END |
DELIMITER ;
```

Your user may need the super privilege to create trigger. [Permissions for creating a trigger in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404107/permissions-for-creating-a-trigger-in-mysql)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thats not quite what I want @WaLinke . Watch the code I tried now.

Comment: You need to use a variable to get the datas back.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `After Update` clause before `ON` clause. Something like this -

```
CREATE TRIGGER cart_trigger AFTER UPDATE
ON cart_utilizador FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO cart (id, datas)
    SELECT id_cart, CURDATE()
    FROM cart_utilizador;
END
```

Comment: And now it says: _AS_ is not a valid input at this position. @AnkitBajpai